# Rubik's Cube Simulator Troubles

Tags: java, rubiks-cube

For my science fair project, I'm making a Rubik's Cube Simulator. I'm having a logic error with my code, and I can't figure it out. My dad and I have been poring over it for hours and haven't found anything wrong. The action listener calls the graphics class/method only once every button click, I checked. But the graphics method runs three times every click, and I can't figure out why.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Simulator implements ActionListener
{
    int[] sideValues = new int[54];
    int pieceValue = 0;
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    Container arrangement;
JPanel title = new JPanel();
JPanel leftButton = new JPanel();
JPanel rightButton = new JPanel();
JPanel cubeSpace = new JPanel();
JPanel info = new JPanel();
JPanel middleArea = new JPanel();
JPanel drawAndButtons = new JPanel();
JButton method1;
JButton method2;
JButton method3;
JButton Start;
JButton Stop;
JButton Reset;
int side = 2;
int worknow = 0;
int woyrAxis = 0;
int bogrAxis = 1;
int wbygAxis = 2;
int lastAxis = 1;
int count = 0;
int work = 0;
int amount = 0;
int loopNumDet = 0;
int rectX = 190, rectY = 100;
boolean firstRun = true;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class graphics extends JComponent
{
    public void paint(Graphics page)
    {
        if(firstRun==true)
        {
            page.setColor(Color.blue);
            page.fillRect(190, 100, 50, 50);
            page.fillRect(250, 100, 50, 50);
            page.fillRect(310, 100, 50, 50);
            page.fillRect(190, 160, 50, 50);
            page.fillRect(250, 160, 50, 50);
            page.fillRect(310, 160, 50, 50);
            page.fillRect(190, 220, 50, 50);
            page.fillRect(250, 220, 50, 50);
            page.fillRect(310, 220, 50, 50);
            firstRun = false;
        }
        else
        {
            loopNumDet = side * 9;
            for(int i = loopNumDet - 9; i < loopNumDet; i++)
            {
                super.paint(page);
                work++;
                Stop.setText("" + work);
                pieceValue = sideValues[i];
                method3.setText("" + pieceValue);
                switch(pieceValue)
                {
                    case 1:
                        page.setColor(Color.yellow);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        page.setColor(Color.blue);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        page.setColor(Color.orange);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        page.setColor(Color.green);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        page.setColor(Color.red);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        page.setColor(Color.white);
                        break;
                    default:
                        method2.setText("Color: " + pieceValue);
                }
                page.fillRect(rectX, rectY, 50, 50);
                rectX += 60;
                if(rectX == 370)
                {
                    rectX = 190;
                    rectY += 60;
                    if(rectY == 280)
                    {
                        rectX = 190;
                        rectY = 100;
                    }
                }
            }
            amount++;
            method1.setText("" + amount);
            if(amount > 1)
            {
                Start.setText("loop run" + amount);
            }
        }
    }
}
public class sideDet
{
    public void determineSide()
    {
        if(wbygAxis == 3)
            side = 1;
        else if(wbygAxis == 2)
            side = 2;
        else if(wbygAxis == 0 && woyrAxis == 2)
            side = 3;
        else if(wbygAxis == 4)
            side = 4;
        else if(wbygAxis == 0 && woyrAxis == 4)
            side = 5;
        else if(wbygAxis == 1)
            side = 6;
        else
            method3.setText("Failed sideDet");
    }
}
public class setAxis
{
    public void setAxes()
    {
        if(side == 1)
        {
            wbygAxis = 3;
            woyrAxis = 3;
            bogrAxis = 0;
        }
        else if(side == 2)
        {
            wbygAxis = 2;
            woyrAxis = 0;
            bogrAxis = 1;
        }
        else if(side == 3)
        {
            wbygAxis = 0;
            woyrAxis = 2;
            bogrAxis = 2;
        }
        else if(side == 4)
        {
            wbygAxis = 4;
            woyrAxis = 0;
            bogrAxis = 3;
        }
        else if(side == 5)
        {
            wbygAxis = 0;
            woyrAxis = 4;
            bogrAxis = 4;
        }
        else if(side == 6)
        {
            wbygAxis = 1;
            woyrAxis = 1;
            bogrAxis = 0;
        }
        else
            method3.setText("Failed setAxis");
    }
}
public Simulator()
{
    window.setSize(800,600);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setTitle("Rubik's Cube Simulator");
    arrangement = window.getContentPane();
    arrangement.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    title.setSize(800, 200);
    title.setBackground(Color.black);
    middleArea.setSize(800, 400);
    middleArea.setBackground(Color.black);
    info.setSize(800, 200);
    info.setBackground(Color.black);
    arrangement.add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    arrangement.add(middleArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    arrangement.add(info, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    JLabel name = new JLabel("Rubik's Cube Simulator by Erik Laucks", JLabel.CENTER);
    name.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 28));
    name.setForeground(Color.white);
    title.add(name);
    JPanel b1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel b2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel b3 = new JPanel();
    JPanel b4 = new JPanel();
    JPanel b5 = new JPanel();
    info.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,5));
    info.add(b1);
    b1.setBackground(Color.black);
    info.add(b2);
    b2.setBackground(Color.black);
    info.add(b3);
    b3.setBackground(Color.black);
    info.add(b4);
    b4.setBackground(Color.black);
    info.add(b5);
    b5.setBackground(Color.black);

    //Bottom Row, Left Button
    b1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JLabel fillb11 = new JLabel("     ");
    b1.add(fillb11, BorderLayout.WEST);
    JButton results = new JButton("Results");
    results.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    results.addActionListener(this);
    b1.add(results, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JLabel fillb12 = new JLabel("     ");
    b1.add(fillb12, BorderLayout.EAST);

    //Bottom Row, Left Middle Button
    b2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JLabel fillb21 = new JLabel("     ");
    b2.add(fillb21, BorderLayout.WEST);
    method1 = new JButton("Tri-Layer");
    method1.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    method1.addActionListener(this);
    b2.add(method1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JLabel fillb22 = new JLabel("     ");
    b2.add(fillb22, BorderLayout.EAST);

    //Bottom Row, Middle Button
    b3.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JLabel fillb31 = new JLabel("     ");
    b3.add(fillb31, BorderLayout.WEST);
    method2 = new JButton("Corner-Edge");
    method2.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    method2.addActionListener(this);
    b3.add(method2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JLabel fillb32 = new JLabel("     ");
    b3.add(fillb32, BorderLayout.EAST);

    //Bottom Row, Right Middle Button
    b4.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JLabel fillb41 = new JLabel("     ");
    b4.add(fillb41, BorderLayout.WEST);
    method3 = new JButton("Minh Thai");
    method3.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    method3.addActionListener(this);
    b4.add(method3, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JLabel fillb42 = new JLabel("     ");
    b4.add(fillb42, BorderLayout.EAST);

    //Bottom Row, Right Label(Time)
    JLabel time = new JLabel("00:00", JLabel.CENTER);
    time.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    time.setForeground(Color.white);
    b5.add(time);


    middleArea.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel leftButton = new JPanel();
    JPanel lbm = new JPanel();
    JLabel ltopfil = new JLabel(" ");
    ltopfil.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 72));
    leftButton.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
    JPanel ltfil1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel ltfil2 = new JPanel();
    JLabel lmfil1 = new JLabel("     "); //Left Middle Filler 1(To center button)
    JLabel lmfil2 = new JLabel("     "); //Left Middle Filler 2
    JButton lview = new JButton("<");
    lview.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 24));
    lview.addActionListener(this);
    lbm.add(lmfil1, BorderLayout.WEST);
    lbm.add(lmfil2, BorderLayout.EAST);
    lbm.add(lview, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    lbm.add(ltopfil, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    leftButton.add(ltfil1);
    leftButton.add(lbm);
    leftButton.add(ltfil2);
    leftButton.setBackground(Color.black);
    ltopfil.setBackground(Color.black);
    ltfil1.setBackground(Color.black);
    ltfil2.setBackground(Color.black);
    lmfil1.setBackground(Color.black);
    lmfil2.setBackground(Color.black);
    lbm.setBackground(Color.black);
    middleArea.add(leftButton, BorderLayout.WEST);


    JPanel rightButton = new JPanel();
    JPanel rbm = new JPanel();
    JLabel rtopfil = new JLabel(" ");
    rtopfil.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 72));
    rightButton.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
    JPanel rtfil1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel rtfil2 = new JPanel();
    JLabel rmfil1 = new JLabel("     "); //Left Middle Filler 1(To center button)
    JLabel rmfil2 = new JLabel("     "); //Left Middle Filler 2
    JButton rview = new JButton(">");
    rview.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 24));
    rview.addActionListener(this);
    rbm.add(rmfil1, BorderLayout.WEST);
    rbm.add(rmfil2, BorderLayout.EAST);
    rbm.add(rview, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    rbm.add(rtopfil, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    rightButton.add(rtfil1);
    rightButton.add(rbm);
    rightButton.add(rtfil2);
    rightButton.setBackground(Color.black);
    rtopfil.setBackground(Color.black);
    rtfil1.setBackground(Color.black);
    rtfil2.setBackground(Color.black);
    rmfil1.setBackground(Color.black);
    rmfil2.setBackground(Color.black);
    rbm.setBackground(Color.black);
    middleArea.add(rightButton, BorderLayout.EAST);


    cubeSpace.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel topButton = new JPanel();
    topButton.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
    JPanel tfil1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel tfil2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel tbutton = new JPanel();
    JPanel tlfil1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel tlfil2 = new JPanel();
    JButton tview = new JButton("^");
    tview.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 24));
    tview.addActionListener(this);
    tbutton.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
    tbutton.add(tlfil1);
    tbutton.add(tview);
    tbutton.add(tlfil2);
    topButton.add(tfil1);
    topButton.add(tbutton);
    topButton.add(tfil2);
    tfil1.setBackground(Color.black);
    tfil2.setBackground(Color.black);
    tlfil1.setBackground(Color.black);
    tlfil2.setBackground(Color.black);
    topButton.setBackground(Color.black);
    cubeSpace.add(topButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    middleArea.add(cubeSpace);


    JPanel PPS = new JPanel();
    PPS.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
    Start = new JButton("Start");
    Stop = new JButton("Stop");
    Reset = new JButton("Reset");
    Start.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    Stop.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    Reset.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    Start.addActionListener(this);
    Stop.addActionListener(this);
    Reset.addActionListener(this);
    PPS.add(Start);
    PPS.add(Stop);
    PPS.add(Reset);
    PPS.setBackground(Color.black);
    cubeSpace.setBackground(Color.black);
    cubeSpace.add(PPS, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    middleArea.setBackground(Color.black);

    drawAndButtons.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel drawArea = new JPanel();
    JPanel bottomButton = new JPanel();
    bottomButton.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
    JPanel bfil1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel bfil2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel bbutton = new JPanel();
    JPanel blfil1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel blfil2 = new JPanel();
    JButton bview = new JButton("\\/");
    bview.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    bview.addActionListener(this);
    bbutton.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
    bbutton.add(blfil1);
    bbutton.add(bview);
    bbutton.add(blfil2);
    bottomButton.add(bfil1);
    bottomButton.add(bbutton);
    bottomButton.add(bfil2);
    bfil1.setBackground(Color.black);
    bfil2.setBackground(Color.black);
    blfil1.setBackground(Color.black);
    blfil2.setBackground(Color.black);
    bottomButton.setBackground(Color.black);
    drawArea.setBackground(Color.black);
    drawAndButtons.setBackground(Color.black);
    drawAndButtons.add(drawArea, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    drawAndButtons.add(bottomButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    cubeSpace.add(drawAndButtons, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    for(count = 0; count < 54; count++)
    {
        if(count < 9)
        {
            sideValues[count] = 1;
        }
        else if(count >= 9 && count < 18)
        {
            sideValues[count] = 2;
        }
        else if(count >= 18 && count < 27)
        {
            sideValues[count] = 3;
        }
        else if(count >= 27 && count < 36)
        {
            sideValues[count] = 4;
        }
        else if(count >= 36 && count < 45)
        {
            sideValues[count] = 5;
        }
        else
        {
            sideValues[count] = 6;
        }
    }

    worknow++;
    Reset.setText("" + worknow);
    drawAndButtons.add(new graphics());

    window.setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    new Simulator();
}   
public static void L()
{

}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
{
    if(((JButton) arg0.getSource()).getText().equals("^"))
    {
        if(side == 2 || side == 3 || side == 4 || side == 5)
        {
            side = 6;
            new setAxis();
        }
        else if(side == 1 || side == 6)
        {
            if(lastAxis == 1)
            {
                wbygAxis -= 1;
                if(wbygAxis == 0)
                    wbygAxis = 4;
                //method1.setText("" + wbygAxis);
            }
            else if(lastAxis == 2)
            {
                woyrAxis -= 1;
                if(woyrAxis == 0)
                    woyrAxis = 4;
            }
            new sideDet();
            new setAxis();
        }
        drawAndButtons.add(new graphics());
        cubeSpace.repaint();
    }
    else if(((JButton) arg0.getSource()).getText().equals("\\/"))
    {
        if(side == 2 || side == 3 || side == 4 || side == 5)
        {
            side = 1;
            new setAxis();
        }
        else if(side == 1 || side == 6)
        {
            if(lastAxis == 1)
            {
                wbygAxis += 1;
                if(wbygAxis == 5)
                    wbygAxis = 1;
            }
            if(lastAxis == 2)
            {
                woyrAxis += 1;
                if(woyrAxis == 5)
                    woyrAxis = 1;
            }
            new sideDet();
            new setAxis();
        }
        drawAndButtons.add(new graphics());
        cubeSpace.repaint();
    }
    /*else if(((JButton) arg0.getSource()).getText().equals("<"))
    {
        if(side == 2 || side == 3 || side == 4 || side == 5)
        {
            side -= 1;
            if(side == 1)
                side = 5;
            new setAxis();
        }
        else if(side == 1 || side == 6)
        {
            if(lastAxis == 1)
            {
                if(side == 2)
                wbygAxis = 0;

            }
        }
    }
    else if(((JButton) arg0.getSource()).getText().equals(">"))
    {

    }*/
    else if(((JButton) arg0.getSource()).getText().equals("Tri-Layer"))
    {
        method1.setForeground(Color.red);
        method2.setForeground(Color.black);
        method3.setForeground(Color.black);
        firstRun = true;
        drawAndButtons.add(new graphics());
        cubeSpace.repaint();
    }
    else if(((JButton) arg0.getSource()).getText().equals("Corner-Edge"))
    {
        method1.setForeground(Color.black);
        method2.setForeground(Color.red);
        method3.setForeground(Color.black);
        firstRun = true;
        drawAndButtons.add(new graphics());
        cubeSpace.repaint();
    }
    else if(((JButton) arg0.getSource()).getText().equals("Minh Thai"))
    {
        method1.setForeground(Color.black);
        method2.setForeground(Color.black);
        method3.setForeground(Color.red);
        firstRun = true;
        drawAndButtons.add(new graphics());
        cubeSpace.repaint();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It will be hard to debug the code. Can you explain what is supposed to do each button? Or the whole program?

Comment: I would imagine the "graphics.paint" method can get called at will by the system at any time. As long as you aren't changing state within this method, it shouldn't matter how often it gets called.

Comment: As other comments say you do much more than paint in paint(). There lies the problem with multiple repaints - you call ** setText() ** for buttons in paint() which causes consequent repaints of the component tree.

Answer (score 2):

Side note: your graphics class should be called `Graphics` to comply with Java style guidelines, or better yet something meaningful like `CubeDisplay`.

The `paint()` method can be called any number of times by the system whenever it needs to repaint some or all of the component. You should not have any logic in there other than what is needed to do the redraw. For example `paint()` gets called if you resize the window, move another window over it, etc, etc.

The fix is not to worry about why it is called three times, it is to make sure it doesn't matter!

Incidentally you would be better off using paintComponent() not paint(). The default implementation of paint handles drawing of borders, child elements, etc for you.

Comment: Ok thanks, but then after clicking the up or down buttons once, it stays white and doesn't change colors.

Comment: @user3142972 It stays the same color because pieceValue never changes. It seems the flaw in the logic has to do with that.